# Strange NullReferenceException despite null check

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, nullpointerexception, nullreferenceexception

I'm having issues using C++/CLI with Visual Studio 2010.

I have a network manager that uses a pointer to a [socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like so:

```
class NetworkManager{
public:
    SOCKET socket_open(char* local_ip_addr, int local_port);
private:
    SOCKET* masterServerSocket;
};
```

When I want to use the pointer I check the pointer for null like so:

```
SOCKET NetworkManager::socket_open(char* local_ip_addr, int local_port)
{
  if (masterServerSocket) {
      return *masterServerSocket;
  } else {
      // Initalize mastersocket
      ...
  }
}
```

But I seem to get a NullReferenceException on the if-condition. Removing the return statement does not give an exception.

- In the current code the pointer is *always* NULL, I set it to NULL in the constructor and never assign to it again.
- Stepping through the application it does indeed get thrown on the condition, so I don't think the stacktrace is wrong.
- I also tried adding a boolean value, initalized to false in the constructor and checked against that instead, still the same issue. So I don't think it's due to operator overloading
- I tried != NULL as well, same thing

If anyone is able to give me some pointers (no pun intended) or help me out I'd appreciate it! =)

Comment: Could you please post the code in which you use (from declaration/initialization/instantiation to error point)?

Comment: Are you perhaps calling `socket_open` from a null `NetworkManager` pointer?

Comment: The comment from hvd was correct and that is indeed the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from hvd was correct, I was calling a null NetworkManger pointer. Turns out the stacktrace isn't that helpful =)

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Are you making a pointer to a NetworkManager object? If so are you verifying that isn't NULL?